# javascript on hovering a tag, change the to url bar on bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When hovering an a tag, such as `<a href="/question/jacobs_question">`, in the browser you expect either on the bottom right or bottom left to see the URL of where that tag is going to take you, in this case `https://stackoverflow.com/query/jacobs_question`

I currently have an ajax site and my a tags have a href of `<a href="#">` so, on hover, on the bottom of the screen it looks like `https://jacobs_site.com/#`.

Is there a way to change this so that a different URL appears?

Side note: I may not be using the correct terminology since I haven't found anything in my searches.  If that's the case, please let me know as to the correct terminology I should be using.

**EDIT:**

as soon as I submitted, I figured out the answer.  Using jquery, you can use preventDefault() to stop the a action

```
$(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        changePage( $(this).data('myAction') );
    });
});
```

This will show the A tag's destination but won't actually take you there.  Sort of a hack, but I guess it works.

Comment: Put the URL in the `href`? You are breaking the web doing stuff like this anyway, so why worry about it?

Comment: you may change the value of href to whatever you want and use jquery to change the action when click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could solve this problem by adding a alt-attribute to your -tag.

```
<a href="#" alt="url.you.want.to.display.com">Link Text</a>
```

Usually the alt-attribute is used to change/add the text field appearing on hovering over links, images and other elements alt-attributes are added to.

Hope this solves your problem. :-)

Comment: I had tried that earlier and it didn't seem to work.  Not sure why.  I actually answered my own question (literally hit the submit button and it came to me).  It does require jquery, thus I wouldn't recommend it in ever scenario though.